# How do we conduct the infimum of $inf_y()+⟨∇(),−⟩+\frac{L}{2}‖−‖^2$ in the quadratic upper bound

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I am trying to understand the Consequence of quadratic upper bound in the 16th slide of [UCLA ese236c](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf). The left-hand side of the inequity is still confusing to me. I know in this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234002/lower-bound-of-a-special-type-of-convex-functions/234120#234120), someone gave an explanation, but he concluded the infimum in one step without explanation.
[answer from another question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WLu4.png)
How do we get the infimum?